# python dictionary: How to get all keys with specific values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, filtering

Is it possible to get all keys in a dictionary with values above a threshold?

A dictionary could look like:

```py
mydict = {(0,1,2): "16", (2,3,4): "19"}
```

The threshold could be 17 for example.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Of course it is possible. We can simply write:

```
[k for k,v in mydict.items() if float(v) >= 17]
```

Or in the case you work with [python-2.7](/questions/tagged/python-2.7), you - like [@NoticeMeSenpai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664247/python-dictionary-how-to-get-all-keys-with-specific-values/44664263?noredirect=1#comment76314367_44664263) says - better use:

```
[k for k,v in mydict.iteritems() if float(v) >= 17]
```

This is a *list comprehension*. We iterate through the key-value pairs in the `mydict` dictionary. Next we convert the value `v` into a `float(v)` and check if that float is greater than or equal to 17. If that is the case, we add the key `k` to the list.

For your given `mydict`, this generates:

```
>>> [k for k,v in mydict.items() if float(v) >= 17]
[(2, 3, 4)]
```

So a list containing the *single* key that satisfied the condition here: `(2,3,4)`.

Answer (score 1):

One can use `filter()` function here.

```py
list(filter(lambda k: float(mydict[k]) >= 17, mydict))
```

Another even more convoluted way is to create boolean selectors and compress similar to how boolean indexing works in pandas/numpy.

```py
# using built-in methods
from itertools import compress, repeat
import operator
list(compress(mydict, map(operator.ge, map(float, mydict.values()), repeat(17))))
# or using a lambda
list(compress(mydict, map(lambda x: float(x) >= 17, mydict.values())))
```

Speaking of pandas/numpy, if you need to filter keys by values repeatedly, pandas Series or numpy array is a useful data type to store the data in, so that this kind of filtering can be done vectorially in a more efficient way.

Using pandas Series:

```py
import pandas as pd
my_srs = pd.Series(mydict).astype(int)
my_srs.index[my_srs >= 17].tolist()
```

Using numpy arrays (will have to create two arrays, one for the keys and another for the values and use the values array to filter the keys array):

```py
import numpy as np
keys = np.array(list(mydict.keys()), dtype=object)
values = np.array(list(mydict.values()), dtype=float)
keys[values >= 17].tolist()
```

Using numpy structured array:

```py
import numpy as np
arr = np.array(list(mydict.items()), dtype=[('keys', object), ('values', int)])
arr['keys'][arr['values'] >= 17]
```

Comment: Notice that `filter` and `lambda` used here are considered unpythonic and were about to be "cut" from python 3 by Guido himself (https://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=98196). But I nevertheless appreciated the variety provided by this answer:)